# Android - can only save files when connected to PC

Tags: android, actionscript-3, file, air, save

I am devoloping an app where at certain points the user can save an image file to the sdcard.
All works fine when the phone is connected to the PC but when I disconnect my phone and launch the app, the file saving does not work.

I am guessing that I should use a different path to save when not connected to a PC?

my current path is

```
    "//mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/image"+Math.random()*10000+".jpg"
```

I am using pure AS3 AIR to develop.

here's the code:

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(Main.instance.stage.stageWidth, Main.instance.stage.stageHeight);
        bmd.draw(_board)
        var je:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
        var ba:ByteArray = je.encode(bmd); 

        var fl:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("//mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/image"+Math.random()*10000+".jpg"); 
        try{
          var fs:FileStream=new FileStream;
          fs.open(fl,FileMode.WRITE);
          fs.writeBytes(ba,0,ba.length);
          fs.close();
        }
            catch(e:Error){
                Main.instance.tf.text = e.message;

            }
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: have You add permisions to file access ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android application storage directories are as follows:

Directory in which the app is installed (read-only)

```
File.applicationDirectory
/data/data/app.appID/app/assets
```

Private storage directory for the app

```
File.applicationStorageDirectory
/data/data/app.appID/AppName/Local Store
```

User's home directory

```
File.userDirectory
/sdcard
```

User's document directory

```
File.documentsDirectory
/sdcard
```

User's desktop directory

```
File.desktopDirectory
/sdcard
```

Temporary storage directory

```
File.createTempDirectory()
Created in /data/data/app.appId/cache
```

Temporary file

```
File.createTempFile()
Created in /data/data/app.appId/cache
```

Comment: Thanks,I replaced the "//mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/image"+Math.random()*10000+".jpg" with File.documentsDirectory+"DCIM/image"+Math.random()*10000+".jpg" but it still does not work. If anything, can not save the file now, even if the device is connected to the PC

Comment: Problem solved. I appears that there was no problem actually. The file was saving into the sdcard properly - just not showing up. Checked it with Astro and the files are there :)